# How to fix 'Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. ' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I encounter this error.

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

I follow the guidelines on the Internet but i'm still confused on how to fix this error. Here is my code

````
     class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,// add Column
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Welcome', style: TextStyle( // your text
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white)
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                    child: Text('Button'),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    splashColor: Colors.blue,
                    textColor: Color(0xfffe67e22),
                  ), // your button beneath text
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what's the expected result?

Comment: when the button is clicked it will navigate to a new screen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your second page. Actually the problem is in your `main.dart`; You should create a new widget for home property of `MaterialApp` instead of using a `Scaffold` widget directly;

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage()),
              ),
              child: Text("SecondPage"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight, colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // add Column
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Welcome',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      // your text
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return SecondScreen();
                  }));
                },
                child: Text('Button'),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                color: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Color(0xfffe67e22),
              ), // your button beneath text
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight, colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // add Column
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Welcome',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      // your text
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Button'),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                color: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Color(0xfffe67e22),
              ), // your button beneath text
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there is a error 'MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.'

Comment: Sorry but there is no `MediaQuery` in your current code, can you post full code?

Comment: that is the whole code. The other code which is the " SecondSreen" is just like the same on the other code

Comment: I ran above code and it was working just fine, please post the code for your `SecondScreen`, when testing I created a dummy `SecondScreen` widget and it worked.

Comment: I'll leave in next 5 mins, if you can edit the question before that, it's good else you'll have to wait for next half an hour.

Comment: sorry for the delay stackoverflow man haha so many conditions

Comment: I didn't get that. Is `SecondScreen` and `SecondRoute` two different things in your code? Because `SecondRoute` shows the same screen

Comment: I'll go now for a meeting, and come back in another 40-45 mins

Comment: it's SecondScreen sorry for the typo

Comment: The same error the MediaQuey keep showing when i run the program

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same code? Because there is still no `MediaQuery` used in the current code.

Comment: yes sir same codes but don't worry i manage to  figure it out

Comment: But the same code is working just fine in both iOS and Android, I think there is something you are not doing correct. I meant you are running my full code? How can this be possible then? There is no `MediaQuery` object in the code I provided.

Comment: The solution i come up with is making another class like this.                          class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Comment: OK, cool glad to hear you found the issue, and now it is working for you :)

Comment: oh sir my other question is how can i deploy it on ios device? i'm currently using windows 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200665/discussion-between-copsonroad-and-zion-miguel).